# How to split up voltages

Tags: voltage, batteries, resistors, resistance, series

I want to power up bluetooth receiver module (input voltage 3.7) and audio amplifier module which accepts only 2.4 - 3.7 voltage, exceeding which already burnt the IC. So i got new one. I'm having 2 x 4300mAh 18650 battery which gives 3.7 voltage each. When i connected both batteries in series and connected both modules in series, (i thought the voltage will split up, but as i already mentioned, it burnt the amplifier(PAM8403) IC). Since i'm very new to electronics, i somehow figured out resistor (V=IR) will do the job but i don't know how to calculate the required resistance.

Comment: PAM8403 2.5 to 5.5V 6V=Abs Max

Comment: Now that you know to connect the batteries in parallel, you also should not let the batteries discharge below 3V.  If you let them discharge down to 2.4V you will severely shorten their cycle life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqMMKm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You simply cannot use V=IR for this problem. The current these modules take varies every time. So the I is not constant and the required R will vary every time.

What you should do is using the batteries in parallel so they will give you 3.7V output but an increased capacity - 8600mAh. Then use those two parallel batteries to power the both devices in parallel.

And by the way, PAM8403 works well with a power supply until 5V. I've used it myself.

P.S. - Ignore the OP Amp symbols I've used to the draw the schematic. They are your Amp and BT Audio module.

Comment: Does connecting the batteries and circuits in parallel decreases the voltage rapidly? (Based on my assumption, Connecting batteries in series delivers 7 volt, so takes more time for voltage to drop. And when connecting in parallel delivers 3.7 volt only which will drop fast and stops circuits from working. Sorry if i misunderstood entire concept totally)

Comment: @DeebashD Yeah, you kind of misunderstood it. Think of it as a two water tanks feeding water to a tap. No matter how you connect, (outlet of one tank to input of the other or both outlets together feeding the tap) at a constant flow rate, you have the same time until the both tanks are empty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, connecting both batteries in series will raise the effective voltage to 3.7 * 2 = 7.4v. If your theory worked, each device would take roughly half of it. But, it is not the case, if one of the device needs to consume less current, it will most likely not take the voltage accordingly and you will have some weird and unpredictable behavior.

Each module should be powered in a parallel topology and both batteries should be joined together in parallel. That way, you will have 3.7v to each device. If you want to reduce the voltage for the second module, you can use a regulator of some sort or a voltage divider (Not exactly an optimal solution, but perfect for learning about electronics).

Comment: Your information is really helpful. Does connecting the batteries and circuits in parallel decreases the voltage rapidly? (Based on my assumption, Connecting batteries in series delivers 7 volt, so takes more time for voltage to drop. And when connecting in parallel delivers 3.7 volt only which will drop fast and stops circuits from working. Sorry if i misunderstood entire concept totally)

Comment: The voltage will change according to the state of charge of the battery and its chemistry. In your case, you are using (I think) some kind of lithium ion battery. Their characteristic is that they don't loose a lot of voltage during discharge: https://www.powerstream.com/18650-high-discharge-rate.htm. When combining in series you increase the voltage without increase the time capacity. You do that when you need more voltage. When combining in parallel you keep the same voltage, but increase the battery capacity. Putting two battery in parallel instead of one will roughly double your autonomy